A word that means "two things in the same location at different times"
I'm writing a school report on the invention of astrology, the [blank] is where I'm looking for the word to use. A word describing two things in the same location at different times, but in context to the below excerpt from my paper.
This isn't a question about astrology and I'm not asking for corrections or fact checks regarding, I just need the word to use for what I'm trying to say. Does anyone know what would fit here?

This apparent movement of the sun on a path across the sky gave the creators of the zodiac signs the notion that, it's possible that where the sun passes through on this path could very well be [Blank] with/of the constellation seen in that same spot in the sky at night.


Are you looking for a synonym of coordinates that indicate the exact position of a point ?

Is there a reason you need a single word rather than a phrase such as "in the same place as"?

This is difficult because the notion of a static Earth is not the full truth (does Relativity allow for any fixed point in the universe?) Even 'The Earth goes round the Sun, not the other way round' is a dumbing down. But inaccurately assuming fixed points in space, 'occupies the same point at time T₂ as the Sun did/will do at time T₁/₃'.

Yea no the paragraph before this was

I suggest coincident: "Occurring together in space or time"
In the paragraph, the sun and the constellation are at the same position. Though it's at different times, I think using "coincident", which applies only to the position, is sufficient to express the situation.
